# When to use „bei“ and „in“

Tags: word-usage, usage

So, there are few ways to denote one object inside of other. There are:  “in”, “auf”, “bei”. May be something else? So how do I know, which one to use where? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to google for "German prepositions"? When I search for it, I get as the first finding this very good site: https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/prepositions/types

Answer (score 2):

The only of the mentioned prepositions that actually means a object being inside of another is “in”. “Auf” means that an object is on top of another object. “Bei” means that an object is in the near vicinity of another object.

The reasons why the others will probably also be listed in a dictionary, is because we Germans have a different concept when it comes of object relations in some situations. For example in English you say “in the world” because you mean something like “in the universe”. In German the translation would be “auf der Welt” because we say it more in the sense of “on the earth”. In the future when humans travel across different planets regularly we might have to adapt though :-)